# How to be redirected to identity server login in angular?

Tags: angular, identityserver4

I would like to be redirected right away to the identity server when a user accesses the application. With the current setup, I have a login button which redirects the user to the ID server  upon clicking but I will like to remove this button so that it happens when the application is opened.

Here is my app.component.ts file

```
import { OidcSecurityService } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, public oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) {
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {

    this.oidcSecurityService
    .checkAuth()
    .subscribe((auth) => console.log('is authenticated', auth));
    
  login() {
    this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
  }
}
```

And the corresponding html

```
<div>
    <button (click)="login()">Login</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a valid option for you I personally recommend to switch to angular-oauth2-oidc. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc)

You could do this then in app.component.ts:

```
this.oauthService.tryLogin().then((success: boolean) => {
  if (!success) this.oauthService.initCodeFlow();
});
```

Comment: switching to angular-oauth2-oidc makes it easier to implement. I found out the redirect to ID server could be done with this.oAuthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin(). Thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: Your welcome. I implemented OAuth2/oidc several times exactly with this lib and I always implemented it very fast thanks to it. Others often didn't believe how fast it got to work :D

Comment: Yes it is indeed fast. Just one more question on this. I will set like an expiration time where the user needs to redirected back to the login page. From the server side, i set IdentityTokenLifetime to 60 seconds but it does not have any effect.  any idea how to achieve that from the angular side?

Comment: You could activate the silent refresh approach for example, so the token will be refreshed without noticing for the user

Answer (score 0):

Import {Router} from Router. Set it up on toyr constructor  `router: Router` and then

```
this.oidcSecurityService.checkAuth().subscribe((auth) => router.navigateByUrl('Your URL');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem with the help of an auth guard by implementing the [CanActivate interface](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate). Navigation to a route is cancelled if *canActivate* returns false, we can use that to authorize our user / redirect our user to a login page.

Every route which requires an authenticated user would reference your auth guard inside the canActivate property in the route definition.

```
  { 
    path: 'admin', 
    component: AdminComponent, 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
```

Auth guard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService ) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.oidcSecurityService.checkAuth().pipe(
     tap(isAuthenticated => {
         if (!isAuthenticated) {
             this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
         }
     })
   );
  }
```

If you need more help, look into the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#canactivate-requiring-authentication). The docs don't offern an example with observables though.